# Using abigen with combined-json option generates nothing

Tags: go-ethereum, abi, golang, abigen

I was trying to generate go binding using following commands:

```sh
abigen --combined-json UniswapV2PriceOracle.json --pkg abi --type UniswapV2 --out UniswapV2.go
```

It doesn't give any error, but the go file that generated bacisly has nothing:

```go
// Code generated - DO NOT EDIT.
// This file is a generated binding and any manual changes will be lost.

package abi

import (
    "errors"
    "math/big"
    "strings"

    ethereum "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/event"
)

// Reference imports to suppress errors if they are not otherwise used.
var (
    _ = errors.New
    _ = big.NewInt
    _ = strings.NewReader
    _ = ethereum.NotFound
    _ = bind.Bind
    _ = common.Big1
    _ = types.BloomLookup
    _ = event.NewSubscription
    _ = abi.ConvertType
)
```

Then I tried this command,but it produce an error:

```sh
$ abigen --abi UniswapV2PriceOracle.json --pkg abi --type UniswapV2 --out UniswapV2.go
$ Fatal: Failed to generate ABI binding: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []struct { Type string; Name string; Inputs []abi.Argument; Outputs []abi.Argument; StateMutability string; Constant bool; Payable bool; Anonymous bool }
```

This is the `UniswapV2PriceOracle.json` file i was using. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

```json
{
  "_format": "hh-sol-artifact-1",
  "contractName": "UniswapV2PriceOracle",
  "sourceName": "contracts/price/UniswapV2PriceOracle.sol",
  "abi": [
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "contract IUniswapV2Factory",
          "name": "_factory",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "_wethAddress",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "factory",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "contract IUniswapV2Factory",
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "token",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "amount",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "tokenValue",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "wethAddress",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "address",
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    }
  ],
  "bytecode": "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",
  "deployedBytecode": "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",
  "linkReferences": {},
  "deployedLinkReferences": {}
}
```